# Tried to import googletrans to use it with tkinter and got this error

Tags: python, tkinter

I use python3.6.0 (googletrans3.0). I import googletrans3.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\traduction essai.py", line 3, in <module>
    import googletrans
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from googletrans.client import Translator
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 10, in <module>
    import httpcore
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._async.connection_pool import AsyncConnectionPool
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_async\connection_pool.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .._backends.auto import AsyncLock, AsyncSemaphore, AutoBackend
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_backends\auto.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sniffio
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sniffio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._impl import (
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sniffio\_impl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from contextvars import ContextVar
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\contextvars\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import immutables
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\immutables\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ._protocols import MapKeys as MapKeys
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\immutables\_protocols.py", line 6, in <module>
    from typing import NoReturn
ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn'
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP38r.png)

Comment: Looks like you need a newer version of Python

Comment: Specifically, Python 3.6.2 added the `NoReturn` name that's mentioned in the error message.